# How to implement "CodeIgniter 2.0" code completion capabilities with Notepad++ ?

Tags: codeigniter, syntax-highlighting, notepad++, code-completion, code-folding

How could I make Notepad++ have an intellisense for CodeIgniter 2.0 so that if I press Ctrl + SpaceBar on the keyboard code suggestions would be shown?

Comment: itellisense is a Microsoft technology, what you mean is auto-completion:  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Completion

Comment: @PeterT: The way it is, people are using IntelliSense to refer to any such autocompletion feature in any editor these days. I don't myself, but I find it cute nevertheless...

Comment: It's `Code Insight` for the Delhpi community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Use a `User Defined Language` derived from the PHP language given that Code Igniter is a *PHP Framework*.
- If you want more **advanced features** and feel **comfortable at coding**, `External Lexer` is the way to go. It's a kind of specific `Plugin` mimicking built-in languages features. Install it.

Autocompletion is language based and has distinct API files for each language.

Notepad++ offers two types of auto completion:

- Function Completion (providing a hint based on a list of well known keywords)
- Word Completion (providing hint on words retrieved from the current file)

To trigger them, you must respectively select:

- `Edit->Auto-Completion->Function Completion`
- `Edit->Auto-Completion->Word Completion`

Notepad++ development community is a vibrant one, hopefully you find relevant indepth materials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that should explain everything you need to know to make your own user defined language [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages)

And Here is a list of user defined languages [repository of user created languages](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files)